# Unique combination with no repeated individual values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have ranked rows based on certain criteria. Lets call the rank columns as

time_rank and id_rank.

```
Window_id  time_rank  id_rank    
   1          1         1    
   1          2         1   --> 1 is already considered, reject this row    
   2          1         1    
   2          1         2   --> 1 is already considered, reject this row 
   2          2         2       
   3          1         1     
   3          2         1   --> 1 is already considered, reject this row
   3          1         2   
   3          3         2
   4          1         1
   4          2         1   --> 1 is already considered, reject this row 
   4          2         2
   4          3         1   --> 1 is already considered, reject this row
```

Tried few tricks with lag , another ranking and self join. None seem to work. I need to find the unique combination with no repetition:

Desired Output :

```
Window_id  time_rank  id_rank
   1          1         1  
   2          1         1
   2          2         2
   3          1         1 
   3          3         2
   4          1         1
   4          2         2
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Well Tim, the op tried a few tricks with lag!

Comment: You are looking for fields that are mutually exclusion.  The generic problem generally requires recursive CTEs, which can be quite expensive.  However, there may be particular circumstances where more efficient algorithms are available.

Comment: Edited the question , added a few more scenarios